# How to Get Last 2 number and convert it to month

Tags: php

I have problem to showing last 2 number from current number. In my case , If i click month march , i get value **3** and this value i looping for get last 2 number from current value. After i get the looping value (result : 3,2,1) i convert it again to month with this code :

```
 for ($i = $par[filterBulan] - 2; $i <= $par[filterBulan]; ++$i) {
        $text .= "
                    <th>" . getBulan($i) . "</th>
                    ";
    }
```

**$par[filterBulan]** obtained from month i already click before.
So if i click march (3) , i looping it to get last 2 number and convert it to month again

#### It's working if number > 2

[image]

But the problem is , if i click month before March (february , january), I can't looping and convert it , because if i looping number less than 1 it will return 0 , -1 ,-2 etc. My custom function to convert number to month not accept number  < 1 && > 12.

#### It' not work because number less than 1

[image]

How i can display **November , Desember , January** if i click January Before ?

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `for` loop, you can check if `$i` is less than 1 (January) and if so, *add* it to 12 (since you're dealing with negative numbers). For example:

```
if ($i < 1) {
    $month = 12 + $i;
    // 12 + 0 = 12 (December)
    // 12 + -1 = 11 (November)
    // 12 + -2 = 10 (October)
    // ...etc
} else {
    $month = $i;
}

$text .= "
            <th>" . getBulan($month) . "</th>
            ";
```

Or you can skip the new variable and use a ternary instead:

```
$text .= "
            <th>" . getBulan($i < 1 ? 12 + $i : $i) . "</th>
            ";
```